# JS function that compare today date to array of birthdays

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a JS function that compares today's date to an array of birthdays and alert users if today is someone's birthday. Below is my code;

```
const birthdays = [
  { name: "Bob Marley", birthmonth: "06", birthdate: "01" },
  { name: "Peter Pan", birthmonth: "08", birthdate: "04" },
];

const today = new Date();

if (
  today.getDate() === birthdays.birthdate &&
  today.getMonth() === birthdays.birthmonth
) {
  alert("Happy Birthday!" + birthdays.name);
} else {
  alert("Have a nice day!");
}
```

Comment: And where is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

birtdays its array for solutions in task

```
const birthdays = [
  { name: "Bob Marley", birthmonth: 5, birthdate: 1 },
  { name: "Peter Pan", birthmonth: 7, birthdate: 4 },
];

const today = new Date();


  birthdays.find((it) => {
    if(it.birthdate === today.getDay() && it.birthmonth === today.getMonth())
    {
      return alert("Happy Birthday!" + it.name)
    } else {
    alert("Have a nice day!");
    }
})
```

and for your comments

```
const newB = birthdays.reduce((acc, rec) => {
  if (rec.birthdate === today.getDay() && rec.birthmonth === today.getMonth()){
    return acc.concat(rec.name)
  } return acc
},[])

if (newB.length > 0){
  alert("Happy Birthday!" + newB)
} else (
  alert("Have a nice day!")
)
```

Comment: that works for me, thanks! how come we have to decrease the month by an increment of one but not the date?

Comment: An integer number, between 0 and 11, representing the month in the given date according to local time. 0 corresponds to January, 1 to February, and so on.

Comment: In situation where I have two people with the same birthdays, how do I tell the console to print out both of the names at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

One reason it doesn't work as expected is that you store `birthmonth` as a string with a leading zero, while `today.getMonth()` outputs the month in **numeric** values ranged `0-11` where `0` is the first month.
Same goes for `birthdate` (only without the range).
A working example should be:

```
const birthdays = [
  { name: "Bob Marley", birthmonth: 5, birthdate: 1 },
  { name: "Peter Pan", birthmonth: 7, birthdate: 4 },
];
```

Another reason is that `birthdays` is an array, and you don't treat it this way.

A possible fix using `some`:

```
if (birthdays.some(date => 
    today.getDate() === date.birthdate 
    && 
    today.getMonth() === date.birthMonth
   )
```

Comment: I fixed it and it's still printing the else statement instead of displaying the Happy Birthday message.

Comment: Yeap, your'e right, there's another big mistake to fix. stay tuned